# Xcode Playgrounds Showing "Empty Image"

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground, xcode9.2

I downloaded Xcode 9.2 today and, admittedly I haven't attempted to do so in a while, I tried to render a view in the playground and kept getting a "empty image" in the sidebar.

Anyone know what's up?

[image]

Comment: Open the assistant editor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48702445/2227743

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, click the assistant editor to view the UI.

In the picture below, it's the icon highlighted in blue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Sam P gave the correct hint, however I don't see such button in Xcode 11.2.1 Playgrounds interface.

Enable *Live View* in the menu on the top right:

[image: Menu on the top right]

And the preview pops up:

[image: Preview pops up]

I find it strange that they didn't make it any obvious :/